Как сделать категории команд Discord.py?
Есть пару ботов, у которых есть слеш команды с категория (с пробелами)
И как мне реализовать так же? Когда я просто в аргумент name ставлю пробел пишется ошибка


https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/search.html?q=sub_command

Вы можете создать группу команд:
group = app_commands.Group(name="action", description="...")

Далее добавлять в эту группу команды:
@group.command(name="blush", description="...")
async def _blush(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("...")

# Регистрируем группу
bot.tree.add_command(group)

При запуске (on_ready) запустить "дерево" для синхронизации команд:
await bot.tree.sync()

